# Amcharts Add Frame to Charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, dashboard, amcharts

I created a dashboard using 8 charts from the amcharts library, but it does not look professional at all. I want to add a frame to each chart. Like in this link:

[http://demo.vueadmintemplate.com/dark/amcharts.html][1]

How can ı create dashboards like this?

Comment: Well, just make some div like this and then load each chart in one of those divs. Depending on the version it has an id property or a method called makeChart(). https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart

Comment: There is problem that ı am new in javascript and ı try improve myself. So ı know that ı have to use div,but ı do not know how it.